# facing an issue while login backend

Tags: magento-1.9, database

how to fix this issue?
I also try to change web/secure/base_url

http://i.stac

[image]k.imgur.com/QytN5.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to make sure your secure and unsecure url are set correctly?
From your screenshot it should be http://saastabazaar.pk/

After that check app/etc/local.xml is correct. see below;

```
<admin>
  <routers>
    <adminhtml>
      <args>
        <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
      </args>
    </adminhtml>
  </routers>
</admin>
```

Then clear the cache by deleting content of Var/cache

Comment: after doing that now i'm facing this issue.
[ There has been an error processing your request
The locale ' ' is no known locale]

Comment: @HamXa Attiq the locale has to do with the language which is a different issue. Check your locale directory to make sure you have the one chosen in your setting. Can you login to admin no? Also, don't publish your actual admin path on here for security reasons except it's a test site.